# Scalar operations during backpropagation of neural ODE with DiffEqFlux on GPU

Tags: julia, gpu

I'm using the DiffEqFlux package in Julia to implement a neural ODE. I'm having issues with getting it to work on GPU.

Simplest example is here:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Flux, DiffEqFlux
using CuArrays
CuArrays.allowscalar(false)

x = Float32[2.; 0.]|>gpu
tspan = Float32.((0.0f0,25.0f0))
dudt = Chain(Dense(2,50,tanh),Dense(50,2))|>gpu

loss() = sum(neural_ode(dudt,x,tspan,Tsit5(),save_everystep=false,save_start=false))

@show(loss())
Flux.back!(loss())
```

and stacktrace:

```
loss() = -24.529072f0 (tracked)
ERROR: LoadError: scalar getindex is disallowed
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] assertscalar(::String) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/GPUArrays/1wgPO/src/indexing.jl:14
 [3] getindex at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/GPUArrays/1wgPO/src/indexing.jl:54 [inlined]
 [4] getindex at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/LinearAlgebra/src/adjtrans.jl:129 [inlined]
 [5] _unsafe_getindex_rs at ./reshapedarray.jl:245 [inlined]
 [6] _unsafe_getindex at ./reshapedarray.jl:242 [inlined]
 [7] getindex at ./reshapedarray.jl:231 [inlined]
 [8] macro expansion at ./multidimensional.jl:671 [inlined]
 [9] macro expansion at ./cartesian.jl:64 [inlined]
 [10] macro expansion at ./multidimensional.jl:666 [inlined]
 [11] _unsafe_getindex! at ./multidimensional.jl:662 [inlined]
 [12] _unsafe_getindex(::IndexLinear, ::Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}, ::UnitRange{Int64}) at ./multidimensional.jl:656
 [13] _getindex at ./multidimensional.jl:642 [inlined]
 [14] getindex(::Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}, ::UnitRange{Int64}) at ./abstractarray.jl:927
 [15] (::getfield(Tracker, Symbol("##429#432")){Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}})(::TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}}) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/lib/array.jl:196
 [16] iterate at ./generator.jl:47 [inlined]
 [17] collect(::Base.Generator{Tuple{TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}},getfield(Tracker, Symbol("##429#432")){Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}}}) at ./array.jl:606
 [18] #428 at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/lib/array.jl:193 [inlined]
 [19] back_(::Tracker.Call{getfield(Tracker, Symbol("##428#431")){Tuple{TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}}},Tuple{Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}},Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}}},Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}}}, ::Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}, ::Bool) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:35
 [20] back(::Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}, ::Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}, ::Bool) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:58
 [21] (::getfield(Tracker, Symbol("##13#14")){Bool})(::Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}, ::Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}}) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:38
 [22] foreach(::Function, ::Tuple{Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Nothing,Nothing,Nothing}, ::Tuple{Base.ReshapedArray{Float32,1,LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Float32,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Tuple{}},CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},Nothing,Nothing}) at ./abstractarray.jl:1867
 [23] back_(::Tracker.Call{getfield(DiffEqFlux, Symbol("##25#28")){DiffEqSensitivity.SensitivityAlg{0,true,Val{:central}},Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Bool,Tuple{Symbol},NamedTuple{(:save_everystep,),Tuple{Bool}}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},Tuple{Tsit5},ODESolution{Float32,2,Array{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},1},Nothing,Nothing,Array{Float32,1},Array{Array{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},1},1},ODEProblem{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},Tuple{Float32,Float32},false,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},ODEFunction{false,getfield(DiffEqFlux, Symbol("#dudt_#32")){Chain{Tuple{Dense{typeof(tanh),TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}},Dense{typeof(identity),TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}}}}},LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool},Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing},Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{,Tuple{}}},DiffEqBase.StandardODEProblem},Tsit5,OrdinaryDiffEq.InterpolationData{ODEFunction{false,getfield(DiffEqFlux, Symbol("#dudt_#32")){Chain{Tuple{Dense{typeof(tanh),TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}},Dense{typeof(identity),TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,2,Nothing}},TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}}}}},LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling{Bool},Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing},Array{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},1},Array{Float32,1},Array{Array{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing},1},1},OrdinaryDiffEq.Tsit5ConstantCache{Float32,Float32}},DiffEqBase.DEStats}},Tuple{Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}},Nothing,Nothing,Nothing}}, ::CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}, ::Bool) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:38
 [24] back(::Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}, ::CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}, ::Bool) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:58
 [25] #13 at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:38 [inlined]
 [26] foreach at ./abstractarray.jl:1867 [inlined]
 [27] back_(::Tracker.Call{getfield(Tracker, Symbol("##484#485")){TrackedArray{…,CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}},Tuple{Tracker.Tracked{CuArray{Float32,1,Nothing}}}}, ::Float32, ::Bool) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:38
 [28] back(::Tracker.Tracked{Float32}, ::Int64, ::Bool) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:58
 [29] #back!#15 at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/back.jl:77 [inlined]
 [30] #back! at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [31] #back!#32 at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/lib/real.jl:16 [inlined]
 [32] back!(::Tracker.TrackedReal{Float32}) at /home/vshanka2/.julia/packages/Tracker/cpxco/src/lib/real.jl:14
 [33] top-level scope at none:0
 [34] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [35] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [36] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [37] include(::String) at ./client.jl:403
 [38] top-level scope at none:0
```

The forward pass works fine, but the backwards call results in a scalar getindex. If I allowscalar, there's no problem of course, but it's much slower than cpu (even for the larger problem I'm working on).

I'm not sure if it has to do with any package dependencies, but here is what I currently have installed.

```
  [fbb218c0] BSON v0.2.4
  [c5f51814] CUDAdrv v5.0.1
  [be33ccc6] CUDAnative v2.7.0
  [3a865a2d] CuArrays v1.6.0
  [aae7a2af] DiffEqFlux v0.7.0
  [9fdde737] DiffEqOperators v4.6.1
  [0c46a032] DifferentialEquations v6.9.0
  [587475ba] Flux v0.8.3
  [a98d9a8b] Interpolations v0.12.5
  [15e1cf62] NPZ v0.4.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v0.28.4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you do `]st` what versions of the packages does it show you have?

Comment: Same as what I posted above. I'm on julia 1.1 if that's important

Comment: Looks like a recent change to CuArrays caused this issue: https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CuArrays.jl/issues/548 . I don't think this is much of a StackOverflow question since instead it's a bug report.

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you know a working version I can downgrade to?

Comment: No, I am not sure when this happened. I'll find a workaround and push a patch to DiffEqFlux for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed on DiffEqFlux 0.10.1. Do `]up` to upgrade, or `]add DiffEqFlux@0.10.1` to specifically ask for this version.

Comment: Fixed the scalar indexing but still about 10x slower than cpu. `@time for i=1:10; Flux.back!(loss()); end` Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: That neural network is far too small for GPUs to be helpful. You'll want larger matmuls to make GPUs effective.

Comment: yep, that was it. Thanks!